# How to give a user the Administer privilege in Jenkins via shell command

Tags: jenkins

Accidentally I don't have my *Administrator* permissions in Jenkins anymore.

It seems everything is ok.

Jenkins log:

```
Jul 24, 2016 12:40:51 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Workspace clean-up. 7 ms
Jul 24, 2016 4:38:30 AM hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: job1 #91 main build action completed: FAILURE
Jul 24, 2016 4:38:39 AM hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: job2 #10 main build action completed: SUCCESS
Jul 24, 2016 9:10:18 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: While serving http://192.168.23.88:8080/restart: hudson.security.AccessDeniedException2: 
ali71 is missing the Overall/Administer permission
```

How can I set the *Administer* permission for my account using a shell command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have no way to authenticate against Jenkins, you (AFAIK) have to disable security first.

**WARNING: DO NOT DO THIS ON A PUBLICLY ACCESSIBLE JENKINS INSTALLATION!**

SSH into the Jenkins server and modify `config.xml` in Jenkins' home directory. Change

```xml
<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
```

temporarily to

```xml
<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
```

in order to give you administrator privileges back. Then enable and configure security according to your needs.

Be warned that anybody else, who is accessing Jenkins during that time, has *Administer* privileges.

This procedure is also described in [the Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security).

Comment: This is not very secure, notice that anyone who opens your jenkins instance in a browser at this time has full access, just saying.

Comment: Sure, disabling security doesn't sound so secure ^^. I would expect that readers can assess how vulnerable their installation is during these moments (e.g. is it a frequently used public Jenkins installation or just an internal one etc) and in doubt block access from other IPs etc..

Comment: years later, I feel more clever. I added now a warning to the post.

Answer (score 0):

go to config.xml and add this part temporarily to the role and it will give the admin right to user who have this role assigned.

```
  <role name="admin" pattern=".*">
    <permissions>
      <permission>hudson.model.View.Delete</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Connect</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Run.Delete</permission>
      <permission>com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.ManageDomains</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Create</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.View.Configure</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Build</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Item.Configure</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Hudson.Administer</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Item.Cancel</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Item.Read</permission>
      <permission>com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.View</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Delete</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Item.Build</permission>
      <permission>org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager.Unlock</permission>
      <permission>hudson.scm.SCM.Tag</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Item.Move</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Item.Discover</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Hudson.Read</permission>
      <permission>com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.Update</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Item.Create</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Item.Workspace</permission>
      <permission>com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.Delete</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Provision</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Run.Replay</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.View.Read</permission>
      <permission>org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager.View</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.View.Create</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Item.Delete</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Configure</permission>
      <permission>com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.Create</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Disconnect</permission>
      <permission>org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager.Reserve</permission>
      <permission>hudson.model.Run.Update</permission>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the question and answer are highly dependent on the jenkins version in question. For example, you can no longer update roles with .xml due to security implications as of 2.289.1.  You CAN, however, investigate the jenkins cli and use that to accomplish the same tasks.  See YOURJENKINSURL/cli for more information.